# Swagger Docs UI - "Can't read from file /apidocs/api-docs.json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to use swagger-ui with the swagger-docs gem. When visiting, the ui interface it fails with the error below.

#### error

```
"Can't read from file /apidocs/api-docs.json"
```

#### public/apidocs/api-docs.json (generated by gem)

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/apidocs/api/v1/users.{format}",
      "description": "Users"
    }
  ],
  "authorizations": null,
  "info": {
    "title": "HAPIE API Documention",
    "contact": "antarr.byrd@gmail.com",
    "license": "Apache 2.0",
    "licenseUrl": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
  }
}
```

#### routes.rb

```
  get '/docs' => redirect('/swagger/dist/index.html?url=/apidocs/api-docs.json')
```

#### swagger-doc.rb

```
# config/initializers/swagger-docs.rb
class Swagger::Docs::Config
  def self.transform_path(path, api_version)
    # Make a distinction between the APIs and API documentation paths.
    "apidocs/#{path}"
  end
end

Swagger::Docs::Config.base_api_controller = Api::V1::ApiController

Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
  "1.0" => {
    :api_extension_type => :json,
    # location where our api doc files will be generated, as of now we will store files under public directory
    :api_file_path => "public/apidocs",
    # base path url of our application
    # while using production mode, point it to production url
    :base_path => "http://localhost:3000",
    # setting this option true tells swagger to clean all files generated in api_file_path directory before any files are generated
    :clean_directory => true,
    # As we are using Rails-API, our ApplicationController inherits ActionController::API instead of ActionController::Base
    # Hence, we need to add ActionController::API instead of default ActionController::Base
    :base_api_controller => Api::V1::ApiController,
    # parent_controller needs to be specified if API controllers are inheriting some other controller than ApplicationController
    :parent_controller => Api::V1::ApiController,
    :attributes => {
      :info => {
        "title" => "HAPIE API Documention",
        # "description" => "How Swagger works",
        "contact" => "antarr.byrd@gmail.com",
        "license" => "Apache 2.0",
        "licenseUrl" => "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about how you have Swagger setup? Do you have `swagger_docs.rb` initializer? The route looks to be non-standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like newer versions of swagger-ui are not supported. I assume that you have added Swagger to public dir with git submodule. So go to your public/swagger folder and checkout older tag. For me v2.2.8 is working.